# Can we color and rotate a cube?

Tags: beamer, color, diagrams, 3d

I want to present a cube to illustrate, and I want to color four of its sides. The colors will be blue, red, green and yellow; the two remaining sides should be clear or white or, perhaps, black. In part of this I want to show one color at a time, i.e. one side colored and the other sides clear or white or black. Thence I also want to show more sides colored, and if possible I also want to show overlap effects. How may I get this started?

Comment: `pst-solides3d` was developed to solve your problem. Just wait for a couple of hours as someone might be preparing the answer for you with it.

Comment: Thank you for this encouraging comment which makes me hopeful.

Comment: Have a look on this example at http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/PSTricks_6_de/36-00-2.ltx  -- it is from Herbert Voss' book 'PSTricks', there are also English versions of those examples/book but I did not figure out how example numbers changed.

Comment: I get the error exaarticle.cls not found.

Comment: @user24406: `exaarticle` can be replaced with `standalone`.

Comment: In that case I got scores of errors.

Comment: @user24406: that example is more like a rubic cube (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc/?page=31) and not like a cube with 6 colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=30 20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=30}
\multido{\iA=-180+10}{50}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
    \psSolid[object=cube,a=4,
      fcol= 1 (red)
            2 (blue)
            3 (green)
            4 (yellow),
      RotX=\iA,RotY=\iA\space neg]%
  \end{pspicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is nice. The two blank sides should be adjacent according to my scheme, and the blue side shall oppose the red side.

Comment: insert `numfaces=all` as optional argument for the cube, then you'll understand the numbering of the sides and you can change the color

Comment: More importantly. (1) I want this in a beamer presentation; is the documentclass used here combinable with the beamer document class? (2) I am not so interested in the rotation, but want to see the cube from an angle from which the two white/transparent sides are visible and from which I see the blue side nearest me, the green side as bottom, the red side furthest and the yellow side to the right - as it were; as stated, one might have overlap effects if that is possible and helpful.

Comment: The `standalone` is only for demonstration. Use `beamer` instead and run it with `xelatex`. The `viewpoint` is given as "radius Theta Phi" and `rtp2xyz` converts it to "x y z" values which are expected.